# MySQL return previous row if no data

Tags: mysql, join

I'm not able to do a proper select syntax. Please help 
I have two tables: 1st contain the working data

```
  CREATE TABLE ProdStatus (
  Id    INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL,
  ProdId INT,
  StatusId INT,
  Date  DATE,
  Total  INT
);
```

Data from this table:

```
INSERT INTO ProdStatus
VALUES
  (000001, 1, 1, '2014-02-01', 5),
  (000002, 1, 2, '2014-02-01', 3),
  (000003, 1, 2, '2014-02-05', 4),
  (000004, 2, 1, '2014-02-07', 2),
  (000005, 2, 1, '2014-02-08', 7),
  (000006, 2, 2, '2014-02-08', 9);
```

2nd is a calendar table

```
    CREATE TABLE calendar (
      id int(11),
      Date date
);
```

data for calendar table:

```
INSERT INTO calendar (id, Date)
VALUES
(1, '2014-02-01'),
(2, '2014-02-02'),
(3, '2014-02-03'),
(4, '2014-02-04'),
(5, '2014-02-05'),
(6, '2014-02-06'),
(7, '2014-02-07'),
(8, '2014-02-08'),
(9, '2014-02-09'),
(10, '2014-02-10');
```

I need to be able to select the sum of all values from the ProdStatus table, grouped by ProdId and Date (sum because i can have multiple statuses) but joined with the calendar table because I need the values for every single day in a selected range.
If I don't have info in the ProdStatus table for a day, then the result from the previous day should be returned.

Here is it the query I have made:

```
SELECT p.ProdId, c.Date, sum(p.Total) as Result
FROM ProdStatus p
right outer join calendar c on c.Date = p.Date
WHERE p.ProdId in (1, 2)
and c.date between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-10'
group by c.date, p.ProdId
```

This query return this result:

```
ProdId    Date    Result
1    2014-02-01    8
1    2014-02-05    4
2    2014-02-07    2
2    2014-02-08    16
```

Expected result:

```
ProdId    Date    Result
1    2014-02-01    8
2    2014-02-01    0
1    2014-02-02    8
2    2014-02-02    0
1    2014-02-03    8
2    2014-02-03    0
1    2014-02-04    8
2    2014-02-04    0
1    2014-02-05    4
2    2014-02-05    0
1    2014-02-06    4
2    2014-02-06    0
1    2014-02-07    4
2    2014-02-07    2
1    2014-02-08    4
2    2014-02-08    16
1    2014-02-09    4
2    2014-02-09    16
1    2014-02-10    4
2    2014-02-10    16
```

Any suggestions please?
Thank you

Comment: Do consider accepting answers to questions you have asked.See more here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work or read the help section.

Comment: Non of my questions didn't received a solution, but i did accepted the answers

Comment: Are you sure that expected result is what you describe? How does ProdID=1 on 2014-02-02 equate to 2? Shouldn't it be 8?

Comment: it is 8, i did correct - thanks. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5876f/15). There is a derived table representing the list product ids to make sure there is an entry for each product per each calendar date.

```
SELECT foo.p AS ProdId, calendar.Date, SUM(COALESCE(ProdStatus.Total,0)) as Result
FROM calendar
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS p UNION SELECT 2) AS foo
LEFT JOIN ProdStatus
  ON calendar.Date >= ProdStatus.Date
    AND foo.p = ProdStatus.ProdId
LEFT JOIN ProdStatus AS t1
  ON calendar.Date >= t1.Date
    AND ProdStatus.Date < t1.Date
    AND foo.p = t1.ProdId
WHERE calendar.date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-10'
  AND t1.Id IS NULL
GROUP BY calendar.date, foo.p
ORDER BY calendar.date, foo.p;
```

Here is using your Product table (assumes the key is called ID):

```
SELECT product.id AS ProdId, calendar.Date, SUM(COALESCE(ProdStatus.Total,0)) as Result
FROM calendar
JOIN Product
LEFT JOIN ProdStatus
  ON calendar.Date >= ProdStatus.Date
    AND product.id = ProdStatus.ProdId
LEFT JOIN ProdStatus AS t1
  ON calendar.Date >= t1.Date
    AND ProdStatus.Date < t1.Date
    AND product.id = t1.ProdId
WHERE calendar.date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-10'
  AND t1.Id IS NULL
  AND product.id IN (1, 2, 253, 54, 78)
GROUP BY calendar.date, product.id
ORDER BY calendar.date, product.id;
```

Comment: Well, I have test it but i relay need the condition ProdId IN (), because i have hundreds of products. So The ProdID can be any number according to user selection. It can be only 1, or it can be (1, 50, 234). Your query works perfect and I thank you for the answer but only fr 1 or 2 values for PrdId

Comment: @SmithMatt - Do you understand how this works? Instead of using the `IN`, you need to change the `JOIN (SELECT 1 AS p UNION SELECT 50 UNION 234) AS foo)` if you want `IN(1,50,234)`. The purpose of this derived table is EXACTLY the same as your CALENDAR table: to make sure there is a row for every instance of the record.

Comment: I do understand. But the problem is that this query is build automatically in a reporting system. User will select Prod id from a range of products and the start and end date. So prodID will be a parameter between parenthesis (1, 2, 253, 54, 78)... I have to use it like this. I can add IN "Parameter" in the query. this will results in IN (1, 2, 253, 54, 78). so i must have this IN condition :(

Comment: @SmithMatt - What it is the table name that the primary key has the values 1, 2, 253, 54, 78 i.e., what table does the foreign key ProdId relate to?

Comment: Products is that table and you are right - that is a primary key

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task for a programming language. How are you consuming the results? Can you make this happen in that language?

If you need this to be a 100%  mysql solution, you will likely need to write a stored procedure to do it instead of just a plain query.

Comment: The expected result needs to be printed on a chart, so no gaps between days. If i will add 0 values for days with no data in the ProdStatus table I will have by time, millions of 0 record and I think it is a good to avoid this. Thats why the ProdStatus have only record for days with data

Answer (score 0):

I"m switching your query to a `left outer join`, just because I follow queries better this way ("keep all rows in the first table as you do the joins").

You simply need to move the condition on `prodid` from the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.ProdId, c.Date, sum(p.Total) as Result
FROM calendar c left outer join
     ProdStatus p
     on c.Date = p.Date and p.ProdId in (1, 2)
WHERE c.date between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-10'
group by c.date, p.ProdId
order by c.date, p.ProdId;
```

When there is no match, the `prodiId` is `NULL`, so it fails the condition in the `where` clause.

EDIT:

I see.  To solve this sort of query, you need to generate all possible combinations of the two prodids and the dates, then join in the prod status:

```
SELECT prods.ProdId, c.date, coalesce(sum(p.Total), 0) as Result
FROM (select 1 as ProdId union all select 2) as prods cross join
     calendar c left outer join
     ProdStatus p
     on c.Date = p.Date and prods.ProdId = p.ProdId
WHERE c.date between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-10'
GROUP BY prods.ProdId, c.date
OPRDER BY prods.ProdId, c.date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need the results grouped so i can represented on a chart

Comment: What do you mean grouped?  This should be returning exactly what your question is asking for.  (I just added an `order by` clause to be explicit about ordering, but MySQL does the same ordering without it.)

Comment: No null values for ProdId - i must always have an id there, and by grouped i mean that i need all date range. so, in this case it will be from 2014-02-01 until 2014-02-10 => 10 days with results for one prodId and another 10 days for the other one. If i select more prodIds, i should obtain more date sets.